# How to interpret "Остается только одно: {infinitive}"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Значит, **остаётся только одно**: смотреть, что произойдёт дальше.

I assume the literally translated "only one thing remains" doesn't quite cut it here. Is it more like "there's only one thing left to do" or "one thing is sure", or possibly "in any case / whatever the case"?

How do you use this expression in general?

Comment: The 1st and the 2nd variants are OK, the rest are wrong.

Comment: Notice, that nouns derived form verbs are neutral (действовать - действие, стоять - стояние). I have a theory that **одно**, being neutral, refers to such an implied action noun. So it is *There is only one [possible] action*.

Comment: @AlexVB and although formally infinitives don't have gender property, they're also understood as being neutral *There is only one [possible] thing* ***to do***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use it when we want to express despair - there is only one way of handling a situation. In your particular example the way itself (`смотреть, что произойдёт дальше`) essentially means `do nothing`, or `there is nothing you can do`.

Comment: Hi. So do you always use this expression (dejectedly) in a negative context: "**You/We have no other choice but to (helplessly) watch something happening**"?

Comment: Yes. Except for the fact there are situations when it is indeed better to relax and "helplessly watch something happening".

Comment: @Alone-zee not necessarily dejectedly, just in any case you or anybody else can't influence the outcome despite being an active doer/participant, like "I/he did my/his best, let's see how it plays out"

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка So is it more like: "**All you/we can do now is watch ...**"?

Comment: @Alone-zee with regard to the gist of your particular sentence yes, however the only thing left to do may not always be watching, it could be any last resort after failed attempts to achieve something by other means, excuse me this violent example, but if a person unsuccessfully tried to receive money owed to him by someone else he may say *Остаётся только одно, пойти и разбить ему голову* (to make them pay)